# SystemVerilog Assertions : Using two clocks

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I need to check this requirement

> Serial_in_FF2_meta_out signal is filtered from pulses shorter than two Serial_CLK clock periods and passed to Serial_out on rising edge of CLK_int after 3 Serial_CLK pulses.

As you can see I have two clock here I wrote this :

```
property Rx_Filter_V3_5_1;
    @(posedge Serial_CLK )
    disable iff(!RST_in)
    (Enable) and (Serial_in_FF2_meta_out)[*2] |=> ##3 (Serial_out === $past(Serial_in_FF2_meta_out,3));
endproperty 
DS_3_4_31_5_1:
assert property(Rx_Filter_V3_5_1);
cover property(Rx_Filter_V3_5_1);
```

The Problem here after 3 Serial_CLK pulses the simulator waits for another rising edge of Serial_CLK ( since I need a Non overlapped implication operator) to check. 
well I think that is normal because I defined @pos of Serial_Clk , what I NEED is for the simulator to check on the rising edge of CLK_int and Not Serial_CLK

*NB:I can't establish an equation between the two clocks since Serial_CLK frequency changes*

Comment: I can probably answer your question (and more importantly explain that answer), but need two things. (i) An [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) It would be helpful to have a/some passing and a/some failing examples in the testbench.

Comment: (ii) Some clarification of the requirement. I see two: (1) any pulse on Serial_in_FF2_meta_out  shall be filtered out. (2) a value on Serial_in_FF2_meta_out  shall be sampled by the first rising edge on CLK_int after three rising edges on Serial_CLK. 

Is that right?

Comment: yes that is it . Actually you have given me the answer.  I will just separate the requirement. all I need is to define a signal in which I would put my filtered signal using Serial_CLK then serial_in_FF2_meta_out will have it on the rising edge of CLK_int

Comment: I'm glad to have helped. However, it appears to me that you need a property with multiple clocks, which is possible.

Comment: Well I would really like to use a property with multiple clocks instead of trying to get around the issue

Comment: your property is pretty complicated to quickly play with. Here is an example which might help you:  https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/multi-clock-domain-assertion. There are more on internet.

Comment: If you supply an MCVE, I will be able to help you with a property with multiple clocks.